# Is there any platform/Office store to publish COM outlook Add-in (Desktop App Version)

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

I want to publish my COM Outlook Addin compatible for office Outlook 2010,1013,2016 Desktop version, the project has been created using the Visual Studio (c#). 
 After some research I found that there is a Microsoft store platform to publish different variants of project (Office and SharePoint Add-ins and Office 365 web apps) but unfortunately I can't find any option to publish COM Addin where i can publish it for public access. 
 For reference I have attached the seller dashboard screen where it asks for which type of app you want to publish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, COM addins are not allowed into the app store.